# Perguntas com problemas escondidos além do que o usuário relata

Tags: suporte

Me deparei com uma pergunta onde a pessoa usava um método que não era adequado para aquilo que ela estava tentando fazer. Então sugeri a troca do método pelo mais adequado. Porém, provavelmente problemas no futuro iriam voltar a acontecer porque a forma de programar, estruturar o código e alguns conceitos estavam errados. Noutra pergunta que respondi também havia o mesmo problema. O que eu fiz no primeiro caso, além de sugerir a mudança do método, foi reestruturar todo o código e aplicar os conceitos certos que a linguagem pedia. No segundo também, porém nesse eu tive mais trabalho, pois a correção para que a solução em si funcionasse, foi grande. Minha dúvida é em como proceder diante desses casos. É melhor "resolver" apenas o problema que está à vista ou o problema de background tambén?

Comment: Considerando que o site não é um helpdesk e nem um site de ajuda, muito menos de terceirização ou análise e refatoração de código de terceiros, acredito que o ideal mesmo seja resolver os problemas da pergunta para depois responder, agora, durante o dia-a-dia só tratando caso a caso mesmo. De qualquer forma é importante que o conjunto pergunta-resposta seja uma referência boa para futuros visitantes. Em alguns casos, até dá para corrigir código, mas desde que fique bem didático, tipo uma série de "aqui tinha tal problema, foi trocado por isso, por este motivo", mas com cautela.

Comment: Cada caso é um caso, mas *geralmente*, se a pessoa está tentando resolver o problema de um jeito "errado" ou "ruim", é interessante explicar pq essa não é a melhor maneira, e mostrar uma solução melhor. Às vezes as respostas só focam em "fazer funcionar" (no sentido de compilar e rodar, sem se importar se o código continua ruim), e isso pode ser até mais prejudicial para quem está aprendendo. Se é pra responder, prefira já ensinar do jeito certo (lembrando que "certo" e "errado" pode ser subjetivo dependendo do caso, etc, mas em linhas gerais é isso)

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente vocês dois

Comment: "_Considerando que o site não é um helpdesk e nem um site de ajuda_"... não é um _site de ajuda_? @Bacco

Comment: @Sam de "ajuda" no sentido de resolver problemas individuais, definitivamente não. Ele "ajuda" no sentido de que você encontra referências e respostas, mas é um repositório de conhecimento, e não um site de "atendimento pessoal", por isso uma série de critérios. No chat já dá pra ajudar com mais liberdade.

Comment: @Bacco saquei. Valeu!